# set image form android media Store to image view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a browse button, for the user to select an image. I use the following code:

```
void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.SetType("image/*");
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == 1)
    {
        ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.MainimageView);
        Android.Net.Uri selectedImageUri = data.Data;
        var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, data.Data);
        SherarClass.Uri = getRealPathFromURI(data.Data);
        BitmapDrawable dd = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        imageView.SetImageDrawable(dd);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It works the first and the second time after that it throws an Java.Long.Error exception.

stack trace :

```
     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod,     Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
     at Android.Provider.MediaStore+Images+Media.GetBitmap    (Android.Content.ContentResolver cr, Android.Net.Uri url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
     at Scannet.Activity1.OnActivityResult (Int32 requestCode, Result resultCode,    Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:556)
at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:706)
at scannet.Activity1.n_onActivityResult(Native Method)
at scannet.Activity1.onActivityResult(Activity1.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2996)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3043)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: Remember to dispose of the BitmapDrawable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.SetType("image/*");
   intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
   StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
 }


protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode,     Android.Content.Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == 1)
{
   ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.MainimageView);
   Android.Net.Uri selectedImageUri = data.Data;
   BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   op.InSampleSize = 2;
   SherarClass.Uri = getRealPathFromURI(data.Data);
   using (Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(SherarClass.Uri, op))
   {
       imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
       GC.Collect();
   }
}
```

}

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri contentUri)
    {
        String[] projection = new String[] {Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumnsConsts.Data };
        ContentResolver cr = this.ContentResolver;
        Android.Database.ICursor cursor = cr.Query(contentUri, projection,null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.Count > 0)
        {
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            int index =cursor.GetColumnIndex(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumnsConsts.Data);
            return cursor.GetString(index);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options.InSampleSize with value > 1 solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. getPic is a button that the user has to click to open the MediaStore to view all the images in a gallery type viewer.

```
        getPic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(it, 101);
        }
    });
```

And then in the onActivityResult :

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 101:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
                                      (this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);

            imgView.setImageBitmap(currentImage);
  }
```

This code will work because I've used it in my personal project. Let me know if something goes wrong.

Comment: same problem with same stack trace

Comment: @Bakri Can you check the size of the image you are trying to choose? i.e if you are doing it on your phone then could you check it through your File Browser?

Comment: file size between 700K and 1.7M

Comment: @Bakri try using bitmap.recycle(); or bitmap = null; instead of bitmap.Dispose; Lemme know if that helps

Comment: the same result i watch my mobile memory free space for first time there is about 128M free when change photo still about 63M free

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the Activity Result as follows:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == 1)
    {
        ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.MainimageView);
        Android.Net.Uri selectedImageUri = data.Data;
        using (var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, selectedImageUri))
        {
            SherarClass.Uri = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            using (var dd = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap))
                imageView.SetImageDrawable(dd);
        }
    }
}
```

This disposes of both the `Bitmap` and the `BitmapDrawable` when it is not needed anymore, and then there is no need for disposing it yourself.